# SQL Server 2012: fetch SO# from a string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch SO# from a string of character in SQL server without using UDF. The example:

```
this is the SO#12345 55
this is the SO12345 55
this is the SO 12345 55
this is the SO#12345/55
```

I want to fetch only 12345 irrespective of special character and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (VAL varchar(23))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (VAL)
VALUES
    ('this is the SO#12345 55'),
    ('this is the SO12345 55'),
    ('this is the SO 12345 55'),
    ('this is the SO#12345/55')
;


SELECT LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1) 
FROM (
    SELECT subsrt = SUBSTRING(val, pos, LEN(val))
    FROM (
        SELECT val, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', val)
        FROM @Table1
    ) d
) t
```

Comment: @tharun just check may be it serve your purpose

Comment: this works fine when u have few lines but i already have a table with this fields ,and data counts upto 5million records.- can you please help me with data when it is huge.

Comment: even though how many records are there it will work fine to pick numeric characters. But coming to performance it will definitely take a toll it's all depends on your Environment ,Table Design and  Coding Standards @tharunthamaiah

Comment: ok, thank you, so can i do a left join with the temp table i have to get the other fields along with the current output. i tired doing it but i get the error as not bound .

Comment: you have posted some data I have given answer according to that ..why all this coming now left join and performance ?? what you want exactly if it will not fit the bill post the other question @tharunthamaiah